# Youtube embed - How can I show the translated titles?

Tags: youtube, embed, multilingual

I have translated my YouTube movies (title + description, no subtitle) in 6 languages. When I visit those on Youtube, YouTube shows the video (title + description) in the visitors language.

Now I have embedded these video's on my website.

Youtube shows the videos with the English title.

Does anyone now how to tell Youtube to show the translated titles?
Here's a link to the specific page:
https://bloomming.com/assembly-video-tutorials

Here is the regular embed code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/skwBNabBX_M" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Hope you guys have an idea, can't imagine I'm the only one with embedded Youtube videos in multiple languages.

Thanks so much!

After some googling I added this to the url - (*for example for the French translation*):

```
&cc_lang_pref=fr&cc_load_policy=1
```

But unfortunately it doesn't do the trick.

I expect this is more for the translated subtitles (*there is no text in my videos*).

Comment: Can you provide a url of a video you've translated - or any other YouTube video you know it has subtitles in different languages?

Comment: Also, please clarify what do you mean by: (`I expect this is more for the translated subtitles (there is no text in my videos)`).

Comment: Hi @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes , thank you for your reply. My videos don't have subtitles only a translated title+description. I would like the translated title to appear on page load (now the translated title shows up after the embedded video has been clicked to play). Hereby an example of a video with translated title: https://youtu.be/skwBNabBX_M

Comment: And @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes (I expect this is more for the translated subtitles (there is no text in my videos)). With this sentence I mean that I have tried to use this code: &cc_lang_pref=fr&cc_load_policy=1 but it doesn't work. I think it only works when videos have subtitles in them and mine don't. I have only a translated title and description. Thanks so much for your help!